# Get subcategory id of existing category magento

Tags: magento

[Code Where is not working solution for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326592/magento-get-category-id-by-category-name-and-category-parent-name)

```
$category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('name', 'Men')
->getFirstItem() // The parent category
    ->getChildrenCategories()
    ->addFieldToFilter('name', 'Clothing')
    ->getFirstItem(); // The child category
$categoryId = $category->getId();
```

According this answer I should get an ID of child category, but second `addFieldToFilter` have not effect, it got all child subcategories and then get first of them what is not correct.

**Question:** why `addFieldToFilter` does not work in my case?